# Android "tabindex"

Tags: android, android-layout, tabindex

I have several LinearLayouts contained inside their respective ScrollView which in turn are contained by a ViewFlipper. The odd stuff is that in some of the Layouts once they have the focus, it starts automatically in a place other than the top.

So what can be causing this ? In order to force them to start at the top, is there something like the tabindex property in html ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have problem called focus is gone automatically on other place instead of top position's field then you have to write this code simply at onStart() method of activity life cycle with respective field id in my case first field 
is referenced by firstfield_et this is the variable of Activity.java file and it is also already referenced by etfirstfield from .xml file

the code is simply as below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText firstfield_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etfirstfield);   
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(firstfield_et.getText().toString())){
        firstfield_et.requestFocus();
    }
}
```